# Can I use piezo plate instead of electret mic?

Tags: operational-amplifier, piezo, electret

I am doing a project by following the steps mentioned [here](https://medium.com/jungletronics/lm358-opamp-eletret-amplifier-circuit-57d99aae772a).

It provides me the following circuit:

[image]

Now, in place of the electret mic can I use a piezo plate?

I need to use the same IC, i.e. LM358.

Kindly provide reasons for your answer.

Comment: Maybe, probably not for comparable results but depends a lot on your unspecified goals.  If you have the parts, why not try it and see?  While if you are buying parts, buy a few inexpensive electret capsules (or salvage them out of cheap broken smartphone headseats) too, so that you don't get stuck without something you might need that would cost much less than another set of shipping charges.  You might also get some more conventional op-amps.

Comment: You may need to change some of the circuitry. I haven't worked with microphones in a while but I'm pretty sure electrets and piezo elements behave pretty differently.

Comment: I need to attain similar amplitude from the same source with piezo.

Comment: Without knowing the characteristics of your piezo-electric plate, this question cannot be answered.  Odds are good that that circuit will not work as required.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using a non-inverting amplifier due to input impedance concerns with a piezo element.

Comment: I need to use lm358

Comment: @AniruddhaSarkar -- that should impact the amplifier configuration.  You can build a non-inverting amplifier with an LM385

Comment: Okay, i get you.. can you suggest me a schematic for that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Electrets have a reasonably flat response while piezo elements have a very sharp resonance and high Q. If you can live at the resonance point it might be OK, but wideband stuff is out. Anyway if it's cheap, try it.

Comment: But, what changes do I have to make?

Comment: @AniruddhaSarkar You need to experiment. Get a piezo sounder and see what it outputs when you play it various tones including one at its resonance peak